# Should validation be carried out at the application or database level?

Tags: sql, relational-database, constraints

I am relatively new to database programming and I find the *coding* aspect of SQL to be very counter intuitive. By coding I mean, for example, finding a single string value in a column and capitalizing it, concatenating it with another value, modifying it based on another table that references it, etc.

My question is whether it is better to enforce the rules governing the data at the database level or at the application level, and why. [This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) (see enforcing integrity via applications), for example, argues it should be enforced at the database level.

Here are two examples, one obvious, one more complex.

If we have a simple Person table like so

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    id SERIAL,
    age INT CHECK (age>=0)
);
```

It makes sense to enforce a non negative age at the database level. However, if we have a more complicated example like so

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    id SERIAL,
    age INT CHECK (age>=0),
    spouse INT REFERENCES Person (id)

);
```

Ensuring that

1. Both spouses are over 18
2. Both spouses are single at time of marriage
3. Spouses are not in a polygamous relationship

Requires more complex triggers. Alternatively, these could all be checked for when adding to the database with far more human readable languages like PHP or Python. If a database is built for exactly one program, then is it acceptable to enforce these rules at the database level?

Answer (score 1):

This is a crucial design question when designing your database and application.  Some things to think about:

1. Are you planning to give users field level validation feedback?  If so, then your field level validation might be better done in the application code.  Otherwise, when you attempt an insert you will have to decode the exception to figure out where the problem is.
2. How familiar are you with the database and its capabilities?  The more logic you put into the database, the more dependent you are on its syntax and behavior.
3. Will the application ever be ported to another database?  For example, from SQL-Server to MySQL?  Or Postgres to Oracle?  If so, then consider the amount of effort needed to translate what logic you have embedded in the schema into the new database's lexicon.

I tend to put validation into the application and integrity constraints (a.k.a foreign key constraints) into the database.  I put the validation into the application so I can tell the user what's wrong with their input.  I think the integrity constraints are vital at the DB level because, inevitably, you will need to make some sort of manual database update to correct a problem, add new capability, or whatever.  The constraints protect you against errors in those manual updates and also against bugs in your application logic.